# domConstruct.create is not a function

Tags: dojo, widget, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Below error is arising at dom-construct.create() in my widget code of esri arcgis.

````
    at showResults (Widget.js?wab_dv=2.12:118)
    at Object._successHandler (init.js:2313)
    at Object._handler (init.js:2307)
    at init.js:64
    at init.js:2302
    at c (init.js:104)
    at e (init.js:104)
    at n.DeferredList.resolve.callback (init.js:105)
    at b (init.js:2311)
    at init.js:2311 "TypeError: domConstruct.create is not a function
    at showResults (https://lr90q4pzw:3344/webappbuilder/apps/7/widgets/DKMtest/Widget.js?wab_dv=2.12:118:36)
    at Object._successHandler (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2313:478)
    at Object._handler (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2307:424)
    at https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:64:337
    at https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2302:184
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:104:350)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:104:139)
    at n.DeferredList.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:105:479)
    at b (https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2311:21)
    at https://js.arcgis.com/3.28/init.js:2311:70 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use dojo/dom-construct you will get above error at domConstruct.create() so please include 'dojo/_base/html' and above error will not arise.

Comment: not required specialy, I think yuo have an error  order in importing module 
poste your require('...',function(...,...,)) here to check imports